# android - cannot delete a record in the database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function that should delete a record in my sqlite database. But it is not deleting, what could be wrong?

```
public boolean deleteLoc(String id) {
    boolean deleteSuccessful = false;

    try {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        deleteSuccessful = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id =" + id, null) > 0;

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return deleteSuccessful;

}
```

it always returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this:

```
deleteSuccessful = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id ='" + id + "'", null) > 0;
```

otherwise there is no corresponding record in table.......have you checked your table for the entry you are trying to delete?

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is of type `string` then, you should use:

```
deleteSuccessful = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id ='" + id + "'", null) > 0;
```

**EDIT:**

If `id` is of type `Numeric` then, you should convert it to `long`:

```
long longId = Long.parseLong(id);
deleteSuccessful = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id =" + longId, null) > 0;
```